# Idiomatic Rust way of making a slice of contiguous integers?

Tags: rust

I have an API which wants `&[T]` to represent a slice of things to sort.

I am indirectly sorting the indices for the actual data, so just want a `&[usize]` containing `0..len` as the starting values.

Weirdly (to me at least) I could not achieve this with any shorthand syntax like:

- `(0..len)` - Type mismatch [E0308] expected `&[usize]`, but found `Range<usize>`
- `&(0..len)` - expected `&[usize]`, found `&Range<usize>`
- `[0..len]` - Type mismatch [E0308] expected `&[usize]`, but found `[Range<usize>; 1]`
- `&*[0..len]` - error[E0614]: type `[std::ops::Range<usize>; 1]` cannot be dereferenced
- `&[0..len]` - ^ expected `&usize`, found `&Range<usize>`

The best I could come up with was: `&Vec::from_iter(0..len).as_slice()` but is this really the neatest/most idiomatic way to achieve this? Could there not be a functional slice which achieves this without an allocation?

Comment: Slice is a view into a collection. You need to store the collection somewhere. A range is just start and end integers.

Comment: Yeah, I know that's how people talk about it most of the time, but I was wondering if that was just one representation and you could make another version which is functional (if not mutable). However reading up more on how slices are represented (as wide pointers) I see this isn't really possible.
It seems a shame not to be able to generate functional slices though, but I guess that's a choice they made when designing Rust.

Comment: The current implementation of slices is the most efficient possible. If we were to allow other types of slices, this would slow down elementary slices, which is a no-go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty close to the most idiomatic way to express this, yes.  If the context clearly wants a slice then you can shorten it to `&Vec::from_iter(0..len)` since `Vec` auto-derefs to a slice.

Otherwise, the other idiomatic way I can think of to express this would be `&(0..len).collect::<Vec<_>>()` which is slightly longer and requires the ugly turbofish to specify the collection type.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't spotted I could just use `from_iter()` directly, that helps (it's obvious in hindsight of course).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without allocation if you have an upper limit on the value of `len`. First, make a constant with all the indices up to your upper limit.

```rust
pub const INDICES: [usize; 1000] = indices();

const fn indices<const N: usize>() -> [usize; N] {
    let mut arr = [0; N];
    let mut index = 0;
    while index < N {
        arr[index] = index;
        index += 1;
    }
    arr
}
```

Then you can make a value with that constant and slice it to get just the indices you want.

```rust
fn sort<T: Ord>(data: &[T]) {
    let mut all_indices = INDICES;
    let indices = all_indices
        .get_mut(..data.len())
        .expect("data was too long");
        
    indices.sort_unstable_by_key(|&i| &data[i]);
    println!("{indices:?}");
}
```

If you don't have a known max length but are okay with making allocations only when the length increases, you could make a struct that hangs onto a `Vec` across multiple invocations.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone)]
pub struct IndexSorter {
    indices: Vec<usize>,
}

impl IndexSorter {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self::default()
    }

    pub fn sort<T>(&mut self, data: &[T]) -> &mut [usize]
    where
        T: Ord,
    {
        // Does nothing if the range is empty. Otherwise, appends indices.
        self.indices.extend(self.indices.len()..data.len());

        let indices = &mut self.indices[..data.len()];
        indices.sort_unstable_by_key(|&i| &data[i]);
        indices
    }
}

fn sort<T: Ord>(data: &[T]) {
    // this can be used multiple times
    let mut index_sorter = IndexSorter::new();

    let indices = index_sorter.sort(data);
    println!("{indices:?}");
}
```

You can put this in a thread-local static if you don't want to pass it between functions. There might be a performance benefit to resetting the items in `IndexSorter`, particularly if your data is occasionally almost sorted. You could also store a `Box<[usize]>` instead of `Vec<usize>` and reallocate by converting to/from `Vec<usize>`, which trims the struct size down by one pointer.